# How to use checkbox to change li as well as standard click?

Tags: jquery, html

I am using jQuery to change the styling of li elements, while also checking a checkbox. This is the code:

```
$(".md-popover-dayselect li").click(function() {
    if($(this).children().children(".md-popover-checkbox").is(":checked")) {
        $(this).css("background-color", "");
        $(this).css("color", "");
        $(this).children().children(".md-popover-checkbox").attr("checked", false);
    } else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#FFF");
        $(this).css("color", "#64a3c0");
        $(this).children().children(".md-popover-checkbox").attr("checked", true);
    }
});
```

The issue I am having is now the checkbox itself is not working. How do you suggest I get it to work? Do I have to write code specifically handling the checkbox itself or is there a better way?

Edit: When I say not working I mean that the checkbox itself does not "check" and does not change the li elements (i.e. background-color and color) as noted above.

Comment: What does your HTML code look like?

Comment: "Isn't working" -- what isn't working about it? What was it doing that it's not doing now, and what have you added/changed since to cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use prop instead of attr for setting the boolean properties of an element.

```
$(this).children().children(".md-popover-checkbox").prop("checked", false);
```

Try this:

```
$(".md-popover-dayselect li").click(function() {

    var $this = $(this);
    var checked = $this.children().children(".md-popover-checkbox").is(":checked");
    var cssObj = {"background-color": "","color":""};
    if(!checked) {
         cssObj = {"background-color": "#FFF","color","#64a3c0"};

     $this.css(cssObj);

     $this.children().children(".md-popover-checkbox").prop("checked", !checked);
});
```

*Also do note that children will select only the direct descendants, so you may want to check if your selection is returning elements at all.*